# How to build a inuitive knowledgebase like Confluence (Sharepoint-Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, wiki

I have now spent some time creating and setting up team and communication pages. We want to build a knowledgebase in SharePoint for the company and leave Confluence. Are there any best practices? There are such nice, useful and helpful macros in Confluence. In SharePoint there are unfortunately only very few and in my opinion very useless web parts. How can you create in SharePoint a really user-friendly and especially inuitive and quick to use knowledgebase aka wiki? On the internet I have looked at a bunch of tutorials and everyone has treated this topic only very superficially.

Answer (score 2):

You are basically asking a Q&A site how to recreate a large commercial 3rd party application by putting together some digital Lego pieces. As crazy as it sounds, you might actually be able to pull this off if you keep in mind that it won't happen overnight and you have to leave some of the Confluence functionality on the table. SharePoint doesn't have "macros" but you might be able to solve the same problems by using SharePoint's native functionality.

I'm not going to tell you how to do this - if it were that easy Confluence would not have a business model - but I'll tell you where to start. Get very good at the following three topics in SharePoint:

1. Taxonomy
2. Content Types
3. Search

Once you've mastered these topics you can begin visualizing how your Knowledge base will look in SharePoint, and start from there.